My Oracle database 21c express is duplicating my query result in the result tab
The oracle database developer is duplicating my queried data in the table, for example, in the attached screenshot I only insert two rows in each of the 3 tables i.e student table, course table and enrollment table, but it displays 8 enrollment rows instead of the only two I inserted.
I tried re-running the code but and clearing the result space but still not working.

As there are different dates on those rows you’ve obviously run this insert command multiple times

TRUNCATE TABLES before INSERT

Every time you run the script (using F5 or clicking the icon with a green triangle with a page behind it), it is inserting two rows into the table and then running the SELECT statements. So when you run the final SELECT * FROM enrollments it will show you all the rows you inserted this time and EVERY previous time that you ran the script.
So if you ran the script a total of four times then the pairs of INSERT statements will have been executed four times and the table will contain 8 rows and the SELECT statement will show all 8 rows.
The next time you run the entire script you will see the previous 8 rows, plus 2 new rows for a total of 10 rows.

To show the difference between the pairs of rows, if you execute:
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

at the top of the script then when you run the script it will show you the complete date (including the time component) and you will see that the pairs of rows INSERTed into the enrollments table will each have different timestamps that correspond to the times when you ran the script.

Alternatively, if you put the cursor on the statement:
SELECT * FROM enrollments

and press CTRL+ENTER (or click the green triangle icon) then it will just run the single statement and you should see that no new rows have been inserted (just the rows that were inserted every previous time that you ran the script).

Everything is fine with the tool (SQL Developer).
Although you didn't show everything you did (starting from CREATE TABLE would be OK), I suspect that table was not empty before you inserted only two rows, so select returned everything it found in that table, and that's 6 rows that already existed, plus 2 newly inserted rows.
To verify it, remove data from table (delete, truncate or drop table / create table), then insert 2 rows, then select.

Thank you for the Answer. But the table was initially empty before I inserted the two rows. Another problem I found out is the ide isn't updating my code, for example, even if I deleted or commented out a line of code, it doesn't update in the result table.

@MuhammadAdam What you think is happening isn't what's happening. Also, are you issuing COMMITs for your DML transactions?

Yes, I'm always issuing the COMMIT. Please refer to the attached link for the details of the recent problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/78775278/18260625

Based on the information you’ve provided, it is not possible that the table was empty before you inserted 2 rows. Your code sets enrolment_date to sysdate and you have two different enrolment dates in the table, therefore you must have inserted rows on two different dates

please update your question with actual code, not pictures of code, and a set of steps you are performing - start with creating the table, then follow with the SQL you are running, from the INSERTs to the SELECTs.
